# How to use The uWSGI FastRouter whith Nginx?

Tags: nginx, uwsgi

Configuration of Nginx:

> location / {
>          include    uwsgi_params;
>          uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:3030;
>      }

uWSGI FasterRouter
uwsgi --fastrouter 127.0.0.1:3030 --fastrouter-subscription-server 127.0.0.1:3131 -M

uWSGI web-app instance
uwsgi -M --subscribe-to 127.0.0.1:3131:/ --file server.py --http :8080

then HTTP GET [server ip]:80/   no response
HTTP GET [server ip]:8080/   got response

Configuration of Nginx:

> location / {
>          include    uwsgi_params;
>          uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:3030;
>      }

uwsgi -M --file server.py -s 127.0.0.1:3030

then HTTP GET [server ip]:80/  Got response

Comment: The key of a subscription is the domain name, not the path (so it must be server_ip and not /)

Answer (score 0):

Do as follows. Worked. Thanks roberto for help.

Configuration of Nginx:

> location / {
>          include    uwsgi_params;
>          uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:3030;
>      }

uWSGI FasterRouter
uwsgi --fastrouter 127.0.0.1:3030 --fastrouter-subscription-server 127.0.0.1:3131 -M

uWSGI web-app instance
uwsgi -M --subscribe-to 127.0.0.1:3131:**[server_ip]** --file server.py -s 127.0.0.1:3232

Console output

> [uwsgi-subscription for pid 18957] new pool: [server_ip] (hash key: 22902)
>   [uwsgi-subscription for pid 18957] [server_ip] => new node: 127.0.0.1:3232

then HTTP GET [server ip]:80/   GOT response

Comment: Can we use uwsgi as the only load balancer? I mean a solution without involving nginx at all.

Comment: I have found it! I used the http-to instruction.